# How a DateTime parameter can be optional in ASP.NET Core MVC attribute routing

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have this controller action method:

```
[HttpGet("GetByUserId/{id:int}/{fechaInicio:datetime?}/{fechaTermino:datetime?}")]
public async Task<ApiResult> GetListByWorkerIdAsync(int id, DateTime? fechaInicio = null, DateTime? fechaTermino = null, int? pageNumber = null, int? pageSize = null)
{
    // code        
}
```

When running the project, Swagger makes datetime parameter required.

How can I make it optional? I removed the parameter initialization but the same happens.

Comment: Optional parts in a route are challenging - I would recommend specifying those optional things as **query parameters** instead - leaving them out of the route. Use route `GetByUserId/{id:int}` and then specify `fechaInicio` and so on as query parameters when you call the URL: `...../GetByUserId/42?fechaInicio=20230723&pageNumber=5&pageSize=10`